# create new dataframe while reading from another dataframe row in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 different Dataframes with NO columns matching. Then we do some calcualtions and I want the relevant rows from df1 and df2 in a new df (lets say df3) row-by-row.

For example..
df1.csv :

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
1,ABC,"c, perl"
2,DEFn,"python, video"
3,GHI,"web develpoment, java"
```

and df2.csv :

```
ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD
1,X,Z,"c, python"
2,Y,Z,"perl, lakes"
```

I do some work based on columns Col3 of df1 and ColD of df2 and get some value (lets call the value VAL).

I now want something like this (for any  non-zero value of VAL) :

```
df3 :
Col1,Col2,Col3,ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD,VAL
```

Sample code :

```
for index1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
     #print row1
     tags = str(row1['Col3']).lower()
     print 'tags : ' + tags
     for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
          #print row2
          skills = str(row2['ColD']).lower()
          print 'skills : ' + skills
          v1 = text_to_vector(tags)
          v2 = text_to_vector(skills)
          cosine = get_cosine(v1, v2)
          print 'Cosine:', cosine
          cos['cosine_sim'] = cosine
          if cosine!=0.0:
               #print row1, row2, cosine
               dfp = dfp.append(row1)
               dfm = dfm.append(row2)
          #df4 = pd.concat([dfp, dfm], axis=1)
          df4 = dfp.append(dfm, ignore_index=True)
          c = pd.concat([df4, cos], axis=0)
     dfresult = dfresult.append(df4, ignore_index=True)
     print '#####'
```

I expect the output to be like :

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD,VAL
1,hacking using c,"c, perl",1,Amit,Kumar,"c, python",0.5
2,hacking using c,"c, perl",2,deepak,Kumar,"perl, lakes",0.5
3,video using python,"python, video",1,Amit,Kumar,"c, python",0.5
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Don't write like this `if cosine != 0.0:`, since it will lead into unexpected results. Have a look at [np.isclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html)

Comment: @DirkNachbar - i'm in nested loop and want to persist data from rows being read into 1 row...

so df1 row + df2 row + VAL = 1 row of new dataframe